# Combo dinamico triplo

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, combobox

Boa tarde,

Seguinte, estou fazendo um combo dinâmico com três selects onde tenho área ofensora, status e substatus. Puxo a área ofensora e ele puxa o status bonitinho. Esse script foi uma adaptação de um que achei no google, ai eu quis implantar um terceiro select mas como não manjo de javascript estou travada aqui.

A parte do index sem php ficou assim:

```
            <html>
            <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
            <script src="jquery-1.7.2.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.5.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
            <script type="text/javascript"> 


            //funcao para carregamento do status de acordo com area ofensora - Combo dinamico

            function buscar_status(){
                  var AreaOfensora = $('#AreaOfensora').val();
                  if(AreaOfensora){
                    var url = 'ajax_buscar_status.php?AreaOfensora='+AreaOfensora;
                    $.get(url, function(dataReturn) {
                      $('#load_status').html(dataReturn);
                    });
                  }
                }

            //funcao para carregamento do substatus de acordo com status e area ofensora - Combo dinamico

            function buscar_sub(){
                  var AreaOfensora = $('#AreaOfensora').val();
                  var status = $('#status').val();
                  if(status){
                    var url = 'ajax_buscar_substatus.php?AreaOfensora='+AreaOfensora+'&status='+status;
                    $.get(url, function(dataReturn) {
                      $('#load_substatus').html(dataReturn);
                    });
                  }
                }

            </script>
            </head>
            <body>
            <form method="POST" action="envia.php"> 

                        <p><div class="div3"><label>Área ofensora:</label><br>
                            <select name="AreaOfensora" id="AreaOfensora" onblur="ValidaEntrada(this,'combo');" class="txt2comboboxpadrao bradius" onchange="buscar_status()">
                                    <option value="">Selecione...</option>
                                        <?php foreach ($arrAreaOfensora as $value => $name) 
                                        {
                                            echo "<option value='{$value}'>{$name}</option>";
                                        }
                                        ?>
                                </select></p></div>


                        <p><div class="div3"><div id="load_status"><label>Status</label><br>
                            <select name="status" id="status" onblur="ValidaEntrada(this,'combo');" class="txt2comboboxpadrao bradius" onchange="buscar_sub()">
                                <option value="">Selecione o status</option>
                            </select>
                        </p></div></div>


                        <p><div class="div3"><div id="load_substatus"><label>Substatus</label><br>
                            <select name="substatus" id="substatus" onblur="ValidaEntrada(this,'combo');" class="txt2comboboxpadrao bradius">
                                <option value="">Selecione o substatus</option>
                            </select>
                        </p></div></div>


                        <input type="submit" value="Cadastrar" id="cadastrar" name="cadastrar">

            </form>         

            </body>
            </html>
```

A pagina que chamo para buscar os dados no banco para preenchimento do select está funcionando certinho nas duas funções, porque testei enviando os dados manualmente pela url e rolou legal, mas quando mudo o status ele não chama a função do terceiro select :(. Quando eu chamo as duas funções no primeiro select (para teste) muda os dois combos, mas eu preciso do status pra ter o substatus.

Alguém pode me ajudar?? Por favor!! Porfavorporfavorr
Muito obrigada!

Comment: Você tem 3 selects, onde apenas o primeiro está preenchido o segundo será populado de acordo com a escolha feito no primeiro o terceiro de acordo com a escolha feita no segundo select. É isso mesmo?

Comment: Aloísio, o terceiro depende da escolha do primeiro e do segundo. Preciso dos dois dados, são duas condições no where do terceiro.

Comment: Seguinte... você está chamando a função para fazer a requisição ajax para preencher o terceiro quando vc faz a escolha no segundo e clica em outra parte da página (onBlur) e então você usa os parametros obtidos no primeiro select e no segundo.. para que o resultado dessa requisição popule o terceiro.

Comment: micha sugestão seria você usar o onChange, ai ele faz a requisição quando você mudar e não quando vc ir para outra parte da página, isto é quando vc fizer a escolha na lista ele faz a requisição. Mas podem haver outros problemas talvez o script não esteja preparado para conseguir montar a condição e por isso não popule o terceiro.

Comment: Obrigada Aloisio, mas eu estou usando o onchange mesmo, para chamar tanto a primeira função (segundo combo) quanto a segunda. Ai penso se se a segunda função _(buscar_sub)_ está escrita incorretamente por isso não esta executando.

Comment: Vamos lá rsrsr muita interação mas o importante é ajudar vou dar uma olhada no código com calma e te passo um parecer

Comment: Alguém pode me ajudar???

Comment: Puxa vida rsrsrs acabei me esquecendo :D seguinte quero ajudar, mas preciso ver coisas como o backend e ver como estão os códigos.. trabalho com isso há anos e coisas bizarras já fizeram meus códigos pararem de funcionar, (uma invisível sinalização de quebra de linha) sendo assim há uma maneira de colaborativamente tertar esses códigos e providenciar a solução que você precisa?

Comment: Aloisio!!! hahahaha Obrigada pela sua disposição!
O que você sugere? Posso te enviar tudo de alguma forma, nem implantei ainda, quero fazer os combos funcionares pra depois colocar no local em que utilizarei de fato. Posso mandar os códigos e as tabelas.

Comment: Pode mandar para aloiso_gomes@hotmail.com, tmb é conta skype. Aos fds costumo ficar mais tranquilo e podemos tentar resolver essa parada :D